# How to set the class of a vb.NET control after it's been created already

Tags: vb.net, winforms, custom-controls

I have a Windows Form with 7 Picture Boxes on it that are called PropButton1 through to PropButton7. I know they aren't buttons but I'm using them as buttons anyway (normal buttons aren't suitable for this purpose).

I want to add a custom "File Path" property to the Picture Boxes. To do this I've created a separate class that inherits the PictureBox class:

```
Public Class PropButton
    Inherits PictureBox
    Private SoundFilePath As String

    Public Property SoundFile() As String
        Get
            Return SoundFilePath
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            SoundFilePath = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

I want to convert the original Picture Boxes from PictureBox to PropButton so I can read and write to things like PropButton1.SoundFilePath and I preferably want to do this without having to delete all of my Picture Boxes and start again. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If that is all that is added to the std Picbox, you could just use a Dictionary(Picbox, string) to associate the file with each picbox.  Otherwise, you *can* edit the designer file, there would be 3-4 places to make changes for each PicBox.  Just replacing them would be easier and less error prone - if you botch the designer edits the form wont load at all in the designer.

Comment: You can leave the original pictureboxes using the tag property for SoundFilePath .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Visual Studio look to the right in the Solution Explorer. It has a toolbar button to Show all files. Click it and you will see that you can expand the tree nodes for the forms and they contain three files. One that contains your source code, and another one called a Designer. The Designer file is automatically generated by Visual Studio and in most cases it should not be touched.

When you open the designer file you see all the initializations of the controls on your form and their declarations. Here you can easily change the declarations of your pictureboxes so that they are created as PropButtons instead.

Just be careful what you change here, because it can mess up the Visual Studio designer. But it is good to know what happens behind the scenes.

Look here first:
[image]

Change this...
[image]

...to this.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is possible with the text editor.  The Visual Basic IDE hides too much information, first thing you want to do is click the "Show All Files" icon in the Solution Explorer window.  That adds a node next to your form in the same window, open it and double-click the Designer.vb file.  Note the InitializeComponent() method and the declarations at the bottom of the file, you see the PictureBoxes being declared and initialized.

You can now simply Edit+Replace "System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox" with "PropButton".

Ensure you have a good backup before you do this.